# Why isn't BFTask recognized in the AWS SDK 2.2.0?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, sdk

I receive an imcompatible block pointer error when using BFTask in the AWS SDK in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

`BFTask` was renamed to `AWSTask` with the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS 2.2.0. See our [blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx31LFFH2WPO706/AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-iOS-2-2-0) for more details.